# Node child_process.spawn not outputting grep on OSX Terminal

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to search through files using a Node app, but for some reason the "grep" command isn't outputting anything. I've done this for other commands like "git" with no troubles.

Here's the code:

```
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

var spawnProcess = spawn('grep', [
  '--extended-regexp',
  '--files-with-matches',
  '--ignore-case',
  '--recursive',
  `"${process.argv[2]}"`,
  `${process.argv[3]}`
]);

spawnProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString() + '\n');
});

spawnProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString() + '\n');
});

spawnProcess.on('close', (code) => {
  resolve();
});
```

EDIT: And I'd like to add that I've checked `ps aux` and the command is running with the right parameters. If I copy the command from ps and run it in the terminal it works fine and shows output.

EDIT 2: Its probably worth noting that I'm trying to run this on OSX in Terminal

Comment: Well your code seems to be alright, plus i've checked this over a dummy grep and it outputs, so check out your arguments to verify your passing actual some real arguments..